# Outlook Delete email after is saved

Tags: vba, outlook

I am very limited with my VBA skills but I got so far that now I want to finish this project.

I have below VBA code working nicely in my outlook. It saves required email into my drive.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Only act if it's a MailItem
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item

    'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
        If (Msg.SenderEmailAddress = "noreply@test.com") Or _
        (Msg.Subject = "Smartsheet") Or _
        (Msg.Subject = "Defects") And _
        (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then

    'Set folder to save in.
    Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim Att As String

    'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
    Const attPath As String = "C:\"


    ' save attachment
   Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
    Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName
    myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att

    ' mark as read
   Msg.UnRead = False

End If
End If


ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

I want to now add the code to **move email after its attachment is saved** to my Test folder. Test folder is under Inbox in my outlook.

I have added 
`Set FldrDest = Session.Folders("Address1").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Test")`

under **Private Sub Application_Startup()** and then I added code into my VBA.

Code is after **' mark as read**

```
If .Parent.Name = "Test" And .Parent.Parent.Name = "Inbox" Then
      ' MailItem is already in destination folder
    Else
      .Move FldrDest
    End If
```

No other changes but it gives me compilation errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **`MailItem.Move`** is in fact a **function** that return the object that has been moved in the new destination.
The old object is kind of "lost", see how to use it (i've commented the deletion part in the whole code `;)`  )

```
Set Msg = .Move(FldrDest)
MsgBox Msg.SenderEmailAddress & vbCrLf & Msg.Subject
```

Full code with some suggestions for improvement (see `'-->` comments) :

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
'-->As it is a constant you can declare it there (and so, use it in the whole module if you want to do other things with it!)
Private Const attPath As String = "C:\"


Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'Only act if it's a MailItem
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
        '-->Use directly the parameter and keep it under wraps using "With", it'll improve efficiency
        With item
            'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
            If (.SenderEmailAddress = "noreply@test.com" _
               Or .Subject = "Smartsheet" _
               Or .Subject = "Defects" _
               ) _
               And .Attachments.Count >= 1 Then


                Dim aAtt As Outlook.Attachment
                '-->Loop through the Attachments' collection
                for each aAtt in item.Attachments
                    '-->You can either use aAtt.DisplayName or aAtt.FileName
                    '-->You can test aAtt.Size or aAtt.Type

                    'save attachment
                    aAtt.SaveAsFile attPath & aAtt.DisplayName
                next aAtt

                'mark as read
                .UnRead = False

                Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
                Set FldrDest = Session.Folders("Address1").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Test")
                If .Parent.Name = "Test" And .Parent.Parent.Name = "Inbox" Then
                    'MailItem is already in destination folder
                Else
                    Set Msg = .Move(FldrDest)
                    MsgBox Msg.SenderEmailAddress & vbCrLf & Msg.Subject
                    'Msg.delete
                End If
            End If
        End With 'item
    End If


ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: It gives an error - Expected: line number or lable or stement or end of statement and lines starting If (  .SenderEmailAddress = "noreply@test.com" _ to And .Attachments.Count >= 1 Then are in red.

Comment: @Kalenji : My bad I forgot a `_` (changed it in the edit), I wanted to show the parenthesis that is very important when you use `And` and `Or`. Because what you posted would probably not behaved as you expected it to ;)

Comment: Works like magic. Just removed the pop up as not needed :) I guess I need my outlook client up and running for this macro to be working? I mean as soon as I log off it won't work?

Comment: Glad I could help. For this to work, you'll need Outlook up and running and to be logged on (if you're not, it won't find this `Set FldrDest = Session.Folders("Address1").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Test")`). I'm not so sure, but I'd say that the code will run when you reopen Outlook and send/receive mails. The only thing that the documentations says it's [This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd)

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I thought. Just added a loop with `Msg.Delete.`